# Communicate with Smart card using JavaCard and HTTP

Tags: http, javacard

I'm pretty new to Java Card and I need to create a Web application which performs secure login with a Token. Reading the Java Card 3 specification it seems possible to communicate with the Java Card using HTTP.

How do I get started? Do I need to install Java Card on the device? Will it start listening on the HTTP Channel once installed the Java Card?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I've clearly specified that I'm a newbie on the topic so what is obvious for others might not be for me. And was that necessary to edit even the Uppercase or Lowercase on the original question ??? farewell guys!

Comment: The downvote is probably because the question is a bit broad. On SO or any forum it is useful to have a thick skin. Just focus on the good questions and answers and see the rest as side effects. I've people down-vote each and every answer of mine indiscriminately. That means that *they* have a serious problem, not us :)

Answer (score 3):

You can install Java Card on the token by creating an implementation of Java Card Connected edition on a chip with at least 24Ki of RAM. You can get these chips from major chip foundries like NXP, Infineon and/or possibly some smaller ones. You will need a lot of documentation, so you may need to sign an NDA with them. You will need to implement the operating system. Don't forget to license Java Card from Oracle and run their test suite. For security you may want to implement the CC protection profile for Java Card, after you've successfully protected it against side channel attacks. Don't forget to implement and test the Global Platform card specs as well.

---

Seriously speaking, there are not many implementations out there for public use of Java Card 3.0 connected edition. You cannot just download it to any kind of token.

That said, you don't need a card that implements HTTP to use it to authenticate to a web server. For that you likely need something that implements PKCS#11 or a Microsoft equivalent, and has a client certificate + private key installed on it, compatible with HTTPS/SSL client authentication. There should be plenty ready made solutions out there, some using Java Card, another multi-application card or file based cards.

Comment: Last time I checked there were no JavaCard 3.x connected at all available. Afaik they exist only as research-prototypes at the major SC-companies and may not even use the regular ISO-interfaces, so you should probably follow up on the suggestion to use existing solutions.

Comment: @midor I'll ask if there are any JC 3 implementations out there :)